# How to choose an xsl:sort entry

Tags: xslt

Right now i am using an `xsl:sort` to sort data being displayed:

```
<xsl:sort select="." order="descending" data-type="number" />
```

i can also choose to replace the line, and sort it by other values:

```
<xsl:sort select="@id"  />
<xsl:sort select="@sum" order="descending" data-type="number" />
<xsl:sort select="@count" order="descending" data-type="number" />
<xsl:sort select="@minValue" order="descending" data-type="number" />
<xsl:sort select="@maxValue" order="descending" data-type="number" />
```

So it works out as:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Metrics/Metric">
   <xsl:sort select="." order="descending" data-type="number" />

   <xsl:value-of select="@id"/> <xsl:value-of select="."/>

</xsl:for-each>
```

Fine. Excellent.

### Now i want to parametrize it

I'm taking baby steps towards being able to have the client re-sort the data. The first step is being able to choose different sortings based on some condition.

Ignoring the horrendeous complexity of parameters in XSL, i'll focus simply on replacing the single:

```
<xsl:sort ... >
```

with a

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="1=1">
       <xsl:sort select="." order="descending" data-type="number" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:sort select="." order="descending" data-type="number" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Notice that i'm not even trying to introduce the complexity of different sortings yet. It's still the same `xsl:sort`, just wrapped in an `xsl:choose`.

Except it doesn't work. Unfortunately, no browser will tell you what the problem is. They simply say

> XSLT8690: XSLT processing failed.

[image]

and that's the extent of the programming tools available to an XSL developer.

### Randomly try other things

One of the rules of xsl is *"there is no understanding, only what works and what doesn't". To that end i've tried to come up with other syntaxes for the `xsl` **boolean** syntax:

```
<xsl:when test="1=1">
<xsl:when test="1==1">
<xsl:when test="1>0">
<xsl:when test="1 > 0">
<xsl:when test="1 &gt; 0">
```

For all i know the problem has nothing to do with the `xsl:when`.

## Bonus Question

Can IE or Chrome debug xsl? Can i place a breakpoint and follow execution, hover over variables, step lines?

## Bonus Chatter

The **xml** file includes the **xsl** file through a stylesheet:

**sqm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='sqm.xslt' media='all'?>
<Sqm version="1.2">
   ...
</Sqm>
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I want to point out that (as I have in my answer) vague error messages in a browser are not "the extent of programming tools available to an XSL developer". That isn't remotely true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put an `xsl:sort` directly inside a conditional structure, so it doesn't matter what boolean expression you choose there; the XSLT is invalid. You can, however, do this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Metrics/Metric">
    <xsl:sort select="@id[0 = 1]"  />
    <xsl:sort select="@sum[1 = 1]" order="descending" data-type="number" />
    <xsl:sort select="@count[0 = 1]" order="descending" data-type="number" />   
    <xsl:sort select="@minValue[1 = 1]" order="descending" data-type="number" />
    <xsl:sort select="@maxValue[0 = 1]" order="descending" data-type="number" />

    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/> <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

(of course, you'd want to use actually meaningful boolean expressions, I'm just basing my example off yours).

The above should sort the items by `@sum` first, then `@minValue` and ignore everything else.

To answer your bonus question, I'm not aware of any XSLT debugging functionality in any browser, but certain versions of Visual Studio (and, I'm told, Eclipse) do provide XSLT debugging features, and both VS and Eclipse should give you more meaningful error messages than you're getting now. You could also use Saxon's command line tools to troubleshoot these issues. It, too, should give you meaningful error messages for problems like the one above.